# How do I set the ErrorProvider blink amount?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, blink, errorprovider

## My problem:

The red icon produced by the ErrorProvider blinks 6 times. I'd like to be able to set it to blink twice.

The only blink properties I've come across are `BlinkRate` and `BlinkStyle`, neither of which affect the blink amount.

## To reproduce:

1. In Visual Studio, in design mode, drag a TextBox and an ErrorProvider onto a fresh form.
2. Use the following as is:

**Code:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Textbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "Numeric input only!")
        Else
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There's no property to set the blink amount. You can create your own errorprovider control to achieve this.

Comment: or turn off blinking and use a steady display

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is hard-coded in [Winforms source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ErrorProvider.cs#1329).

It can be messed with, if you really want to.  Reflection can be used to get access to private members.  Normally somewhat risky but Winforms code has been stable for a long time and isn't going to change anymore.  I'll post the C# version, you can translate it to VB pretty easily:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
    public static void ReportError(ErrorProvider provider, Control control, string text) {
        if (provider.GetError(control) == text) return;
        provider.SetError(control, text);
        // Dig out the "items" hash table to get access to the ControlItem for the control
        var fi = typeof(ErrorProvider).GetField("items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var ht = (System.Collections.Hashtable)(fi.GetValue(provider));
        var ci = ht[control];
        // Patch the ControlItem.blinkPhase field to lower it to 2 blinks
        var fi2 = ci.GetType().GetField("blinkPhase", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if ((int)fi2.GetValue(ci) > 4) fi2.SetValue(ci, 4);
    }
```

Works fine, low risk.